# Debugging Playbook using SSH

Tags: debugging, blackberry-playbook

I am using one of the cross platform sdk (marmalade if you need more details) to develop a game for blackberry playbook. The SDK do not provide any mechanism to debug apps on playbook device, so I've to use `command line` to do this. I've searched about this and I've got to know that I need to connect to playbook to my mac over `SSH` connection and get the log files stored in `appdata`.

I am successful in connection my playbook to my mac using `SSH`, now nowhere the next step is mentioned. I've never used SSH before and don't know how it can be used to transfer files. SO my question is how can I debug or get logs from playbook using SSH, once the SSH connection is done.

PS: Please tell the answer considering I've a Mac, not windows PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FInally got it. Actually I thought there'd be some command line utility to find the log files. I just downloaded FileZilla(Any sftp client will do), copied the added private key and connected to the already ssh connected playbook. I can now download the logs from the appdata.